# How to quit cocoa app when windows close?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to quit Cocoa App when I click the red button on upper left.

[image]

I found [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-105229.html) page saying

> So what you need to do first is have the window you want to close be
>   connected  to an IBOutlet in the nib. For this example i connected the
>   window to an  outlet named "mainWindow".

How can I do this? I found Windows in xib file, but how can I connect it to an IBOutlet in the nib?

Or, is there any way to quit the cocoa app clicking red button?

### EDIT

I should have put the code in the `automatically generated delegate file`.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

There is an optional method for the application's delegate which will do this automatically. All you have to do is add this to the implementation. You don't need to create an outlet or anything.

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I guess it's because my main window is not subclassed from NSWindowCoontroller (http://recursive-design.com/blog/2007/04/13/quit-cocoa-app-on-window-close/).

Comment: It definitely works, but you may have put the code in the wrong place. Make sure it's in your application's delegate.

Comment: "If your implementation returns NO, control returns to the main event loop and the application is not terminated. If you return YES, your delegate’s applicationShouldTerminate: method is subsequently invoked to confirm that the application should be terminated."

Comment: Just wanted to give the swift3 version: func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed (_ theApplication: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the NSApplicationDelegate protocol, especially to the `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:`method...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html