# How to quit MonoMac app when window closes?

Tags: macos, mono, monomac

I can use [`- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268757/how-to-quit-cocoa-app-when-windows-close) method to quit cocoa app when window closes by using the method in application's delegate.

How can I do the same thing with MonoMac? In general, how can I map objective-c method to MonoMac's C# function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this code, I see that I can use the same function in the delegate.

```
namespace AnimatingViews
{
    public partial class AppDelegate : NSApplicationDelegate
    {
        AnimatingViewsWindowController animatingViewsWindowController;

        public AppDelegate ()
        {
        }

        public override void FinishedLaunching (NSObject notification)
        {
            animatingViewsWindowController = new AnimatingViewsWindowController ();
            animatingViewsWindowController.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (this);
        }

        public override bool ApplicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed (NSApplication sender)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```